# How to install Gnuplot on mac 10.5.8?

Tags: mac

I use Mac OS 10.5.8 and I want to install Gnuplot. I have found some advice on the net but it is not useful for me. Can anyone give me some clear steps of what is needed? What programs do I need and where can I find them exactly? A step-by-step solution invoking terminal commands would be appreciated.

Comment: Did this answer on TeX.sx not help? [Install Gnuplot on Mac OS-X 10.8.2 for use with 'tkz-fct' package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89675)

Answer (score 3):

http://brew.sh/

Install brew. The website lists the requirements, and the step by steps command line instructions. In short, it's:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL --insecure https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Then:

```
brew install gnuplot
```

You're on 10.5.8 so installation requires '--insecure' as the older version of curl didn't have the CA secure certs packaged in.

Brew is also very handy for installing software in general. It's a unix package manager in the style of apt.

Comment: Alex i don t know how to thank you!!!! It worked perfectly!!!!

Comment: No problem. Just check the answer as correct.